# Telerik Reporting Error: sqlDataSource does not exist in the current context

Tags: telerik-reporting

I am trying to create a SqlDataSource using Telerik Reporting and am getting errors using the exact code in the documentation attempting to connect to AdventureWorks database:

```
    SqlDataSource sqlDataSource = new SqlDataSource();
    sqlDataSource.ProviderName = "System.Data.SqlClient";
    sqlDataSource.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True";
    sqlDataSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Production.Product";
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is placed inside of the body of the class, but it should be placed in a method instead. Use object initializer like this:

```
SqlDataSource sqlDataSource = new SqlDataSource
{
    ProviderName = "System.Data.SqlClient",
    ConnectionString = "Data Source=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True",
    SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Production.Product"
}
```

or move the initialization code in a separate method.